# Change the size of UIStepper?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Is it possible to change the size of a UIStepper?  When i try to set the size of a stepper it seems to get ignored.

```
UIStepper *stepper = [[UIStepper alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,100,100)];
[self.view addSubview:stepper];
NSLog(@"%@",stepper);
CGRect r = CGRectMake(50,50,100,100);
stepper.frame = r;
NSLog(@"%@",stepper);
```

Log says the frame is (50 50; 94 27)

Is it possible to change the size from 94, 27?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i agree with bani uppal . the size of the stepper can not be changed, you cannot implement the same functionality with the help of two custom buttons and can set the background images of the your buttons to give the impression of stepper.

Comment: The size can be changed in a pretty clean way. Set a background image to the stepper and the size of the stepper will change to the one of the image.

Answer (score 14):

You can properly update the UIStepper size without transformation.

Use the following method to set the background image and the stepper will draw itself using the background size:

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage*)image forState:(UIControlState)state
```

**Example**

```
    [self.stepper1 setIncrementImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"plusIcon1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.stepper1 setDecrementImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"minusIcon1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.stepper1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stepperBkg1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.stepper1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stepperBkgHighlighted1.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.stepper1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stepperBkgDisabled1.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

This yields the following result on the left, compared to an unmodified stepper on the right:
[image]

stepperBkg1@2x.png:

[image]

stepperBkgHighlighted1@2x.png:

[image]

Comment: Not sure why this hasn't received more up votes. This is an excellent answer. And this should be the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: The important bit here is that the background image is the one setting the size of the UIStepper.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this line code in your `viewDidLoad`

```
 Stepper.transform = Stepper.transform.scaledBy(x: 10, y: 10)
```

but it will kind of offsets the functionality but give it a go !

Comment: This will potentially distort the view.

Answer (score -3):

You cannot change the size of a UIStepper. UIStepper is a subclass of UIView, you can probably change the size with some kind of hack, might be creating a subclass of UIStepper and overriding the drawRect:, I am not sure that will work. But doing so will put your app at a risk of being rejected. If you need a different size, best option is to make a custom component.